# What does {app, BrowserWindow} means in JavaScript (node.js)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

While reading docs of making softwares with [electron](https://electron.atom.io), I came across this type of code in the beginning of `index.js` file (the file where generally execution starts)

```
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')
```

What does `{app, BrowserWindow}` (the syntax, not the keywords) really means? Is it a JavaScript syntax, or a node.js thing or something exclusively related to electron?

Comment: [object destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) - it's "new" javascript (in other words, ES2015+)

Comment: It's basically just make it shorter to write. Instead of `const eletron = require('electron');` and later use `electron.app`, it allows you to just type `app`. I personally avoid this type of construct because 2 imported modules could export the same properties, and you would not be able to do: `const {utils} = require('module1'); const {utils} = require('module2');`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This syntax is called 'object destructuring', and it is a feature of the latest version of JavaScript (JavaScript2015 aka ECMAScript 6/ES6) - `app` and `BrowserWindow` are just particular parts of `electron` that you want to use in this portion of your application.

It's a way to simplify your code and to easily reference critical parts of a dependency.

Here's a very basic example from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

```
var o = {p: 42, q: true};
var {p, q} = o;

console.log(p); // 42
console.log(q); // true
```

So in your case, `electron` is an imported module that would look something like (again, a gross oversimplification here):

```
var electron = {
    app: {
        greet: () => {
            console.log("Hello, world!")
        }
    },
    BrowserWindow: {/* some other stuff */},
    anotherMethod: {/* other stuff, which we will ignore in your app */}
}

module.exports electron
```

Then in your app, you import this module and you can reference the imported attributes directly:

```
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')

app.greet()
// "Hello, world!"
```

And similarly, you can reference `BrowserWindow`... however, you couldn't reference `anotherMethod` without including it in the destructuring assignment.

Hope that's helpful.

Comment: It's also worth considering that when the *destructuring assignment* "pulls"  the required "members" out of the object it also creates local variables for them. Then the "destructured members" could be changed (unless declared as `const` like here)

Comment: Just here to let you know this syntax is also valid on json files eg: `const {version, name} = require('./package.json')`

Answer (score 8):

I just want to point out (because the OP wonders what destructuring is useful for), that the statement in your question is equivalent to:

```js
const electron = require('electron')
const app = electron.app
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow
```

However, using object destructuring, it becomes more succinct and leaves out the unnecessary declaration of the `const electron`:

```js
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')
```

This is why I use it very often.