# I want to know the const declaration type of js

Tags: javascript

I know how to declare const variable like const a = 1;

but I dont get what is this

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')
```

can anyone explain me?

Comment: JavaScript destructuring, allows you to declare multiple consts from the one value / module. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: here `app` and `BrowserWindow` both variables are available inside electro package as objects. So you can directly take it's object variables into main variables. Check here. It will help you understand better https://stackoverflow.com/a/44905538/4156021

Comment: duplicate of :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44732946/what-does-app-browserwindow-means-in-javascript-node-js/44733043

Answer (score -1):

That’s a destructuring assignment.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

It lets you make shortcuts to members of an array or structure.